# move some files from a git repository to a new one

Tags: git

I have a `git` repository which, essentially, contains two related projects, which I would like now to split. I would like to move the files related to one project to a new repository, preserving the history of changes. To be concrete, let us suppose that the original git repository contains:

```
file1.c
file2.c
subdir/file2_extra.c
```

Also, the original `git` repository contains several branches. I want to keep onlly some of them, those related with the files I want to separate.

How can I create a new `git` repository containing, say, `file2.c` and `subdir/file2_extra.c` only, together with the history of commits to them?

Notice that the files I want to separate are not found in a separate directory. For otherwise, I think one can use `git subtree`.

I tried to use `git filter-branch`, without success. Let us assume the original repository is `git_original`, what I have tried is

```
$ git clone git_original/ git_new
Cloning into 'git_new'...
done.
$ cd git_new
$ git rm file1.c
rm 'file1.c'
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty -- --all
Cannot rewrite branches: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

But if I commit the removal of `file1.c`, then `git filter-branch` does not do anything.

Comment: You nee to commit the `git rm` before `filter-branch`.

Comment: @marekful Please check the last line of the question. If I commit the ```git rm``` then I just get a repository with an extra commit. I would like to get rid of ```file1.c``` together with its history of commits.

Comment: `filter-branch` will still only operate on changes that are committed into a branch, therefore, there's no point calling it with uncommitted local changes besides it wouldn't allow that anyway. You need fine tune how you call `filter-branch`. [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html#Reducerepositorysize-ReduceRep-DRAFT-Reducerepositorysize-Manuallyreviewinglargefilesinyourrepository) you can find some hints in the 'Running filter-branch' and 'Delete files by name' sections.

Comment: @marekful Thanks a lot for the link! As far as I can see, one has clone somewhere else the repository, and then to go through all the desired branches, deleting the unwanted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html#Reducerepositorysize-ReduceRep-DRAFT-Reducerepositorysize-Manuallyreviewinglargefilesinyourrepository) (thanks to @marekful for providing this) I have devised this solution. The main idea is to clone the repository into a new one, and eliminate the unwanted files in each commit. I am assuming one has a remote repository, and each local branch tracks the corresponding remote branch.

Clone the old repository into a new one.

```
$ git clone git_original/ git_new
```

Go into the new repository.

```
$ cd git_new
```

For each desired branch *in the new repository* set up a branch.

```
$ git branch -t branch_name origin/branch_name
```

Delete every unwanted file in the new repository. E.g., in the example of the question, I wanted to delete the file file1.c.

```
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file1.c' \
      --prune-empty -- --all
```

The option `-f` should be necessary if you delete more than one file, as it forces to overwrite the "old" refs.

By a `git checkout` to all the branches of the new repository, you can check that indeed the unwanted files have been eliminated.

Some cleanup.

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Now, remove the old origin and associate with a new remote repository.

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin remote_origin_address
```

Finally push everything to the new remote.

```
$ git push -u origin --all
$ git push -u origin --tags
```